# How to fix, ViewModel doesn't bind to View using Prism Library

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I'm developing a WPF application where I use Prism with Unity IOC. For all other views which are displayed on launch of the application, they seem to bind appropriately to the intended VM (auto wired by prism). However, when I Navigate to another view (which is a within a tab control, just one for now) I can't seem to bind buttons to Commands or TextBlock to string properties from the VM. Note that this works fine in the home view and views within its regions.

Asides telling prism to auto wire the VM, I've tried assigning a DataContext in XAML from the view, assigning the DataContext from the code-behind. I even added the first code below to my bootstrapper to determine the view model that prism resolves to, and it appears to be the intended VM when i debugged. Also adding a breakpoint to my VM class in all cases above shows that the VM was instantiated. 
    // Added this to my bootstrapper to inspect the viewModelName
    protected override void ConfigureViewModelLocator()
    {
        base.ConfigureViewModelLocator();

```
    ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(x =>
    {
        var viewName = x.FullName;
        viewName = viewName.Replace(".Views.", ".ViewModels.");
        var viewAssemblyName = x.GetTypeInfo().Assembly.FullName;
        var suffix = viewName.EndsWith("View") ? "Model" : "ViewModel";
        var viewModelName = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}{1}, {2}", viewName, suffix, viewAssemblyName);
        return Type.GetType(viewModelName);
    });
    ViewModelLocationProvider.SetDefaultViewModelFactory(type => Container.Resolve(type));
}
```

This bit of code is where the tab is added to when I navigate

```
<metro:MetroTabControl prism:RegionManager.RegionName="{x:Static constants:RegionNames.ContentRegion}" >
    <metro:MetroTabControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Rectangle Margin="2,3,2,3" 
               HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
               Fill="{DynamicResource AccentColorBrush}" 
               Height="2"/>
                <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Content="{Binding Content}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </metro:MetroTabControl.ContentTemplate>
</metro:MetroTabControl>
```

Navigation with `RegionManager.RequestNavigate(Region, navigatePath)`
And here is what my view model looks like

```
public class MinerViewModel : Screen
{

    string searchText = "Seacrch";
    public ICommand SearchCommand { get; private set; }

    IList<FeedItem> temp;

    public MinerViewModel()
    {

        this.SearchCommand = new DelegateCommand(this.ToggleSearch, () => { return true; });
        //ToggleSearch();
    }


    public string SearchText
    {
        get => searchText;
        set
        {
            SetProperty<string>(ref searchText, value);
        }
    }

    public void ToggleSearch()
    {
        // do foo and bar
    }


}
```

Please how do I get things to work as expected ?

Comment: What is navigatePath and where and how is view defined? What do you currently see and what do you expect to see? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What is the xaml of the view? Which namespaces are view and view model in? How does your region adapter look like?